# Native-React + Expo: Unable to resolve "@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf" from "src/boot/setup.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, ionicons

I am just starting out on React Native *0.57.1* and expo *2.21.2* using [a boilerplate code that attempts to load a font](https://github.com/Keftaa/expo-redux-boilerplate/blob/master/src/boot/setup.js#L22) during startup with the command `npm start` or `expo start`:

```
import * as Expo from "expo";

....

async componentWillMount() {
    await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        Ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf"),
    });

    this.setState({ isReady: true });
}
```

This gives an error

> Unable to resolve "@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf" from "src/boot/setup.js"

**Attempt #1:** `npm install --save @expo/vector-icons`. However, doing this does not solve the error.

Why is this happening, and how can we resolve this issue? Thank you!

---

**Update:** Following the suggestions of both mialnika and Carlos Abraham, the error is fixed but a new one is encountered:

> The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo.

This is from running the RN app in Expo's development mode, connected through LAN, using the iOS Expo client on an actual iPhone.

No such error appears from a fresh `expo init` project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to load the Icon library like that to be able to use Ionicons in expo, just install the package and use it like so:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default class IconExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks removing the async loading as suggested got rid of the error, but gives a new error `The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo.`. Any ideas?

Comment: Try reloading the app completely, that should work!

Comment: I get the same error after quitting both the server and iOS client on the iPhone, then starting both server and iOS client on the iPhone. Also tried logging out of expo in the Terminal and logging back in again, which did not help.

Comment: On a fresh `expo init` project, no such error appears

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of vector-icons you have but can you check if this link will work :)?
'@expo/vector-icons/website/src/fonts/Ionicons.ttf';

Comment: Thanks updating the link got rid of the error, but gives a new error `The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo.` Any ideas?